# Displaying PDF file in JSF with Object tag

Tags: pdf, xhtml, richfaces

My project uses richfaces 4 where i am trying to show a PDF file inside a rich:collapsiblePanel using the object tag and with the help of a servlet. It works perfectly with all the browsers (i.e IE, Firefox, Chorme) when there is a PDF file present.

Problem 1:
When there is no pdf document present, then in Firefox & Chrome, inside the collapsiblePanel remains blank(as it should). But in IE 9 & above it gives a black background with the writing ' Initializing...' in the middle (which happens when it is loading the pdf file). In this case, since there is no file to be loaded, it remains stuck there. How to overcome this issue?

Problem 2:
In IE 9 & above, the dropdown menu of header menu goes behind the PDF file. Its obviously a problem of z-index, but then, the question is, why does it behaves perfectly in Firefox & Chrome? I have tried fixing the z-index with style attribute of the object tag. Doesn't work.

There are lots of questions regarding this but none of them helped in my case.

A small example of my code is given below:

```
<object data='servlet' 
        type='application/pdf' 
        width='100%' 
        height='100%'/>
```

I even tried with params as shown here

```
<object type='application/pdf' 
        width='100%' 
        height='100%'>
 <param name="src" value="servlet">
</object>
```

Even iframe didn't work. Same problem exist in IE.

Is there any way to resolve these issues?

Comment: Can't you do a check on the server side and only render the <object> if there is a file to display? As to why it doesn't work in IE - IE is weird like that.

Comment: @Makhiel - I used the same solution yesterday morning for problem 1 and it worked. But my main concern in problem 2. Do you have any solution for that? Thanks :)

Comment: There are certain elements that have virtually infinite z-index (e.g. the dropdown of <select>). This might be one of those.

Comment: No @Makhiel, i believe the problem is because IE uses adobe reader plugin to show the pdf file & it loads it in DOM at runtime. So, after loading of html body when it executes the object tag it becomes the latest element as well as the top most element. That is why the z-index issue is coming. And there's no solution for this.